# Nested Repo: Unlink the sub module to github but have parent module still track files

Tags: git, github

I used `create-react-app` to make a react app, the dir of which is called `syntax-applet`. I moved that directory inside another (Github repo)directory. I want to unlink `syntax-applet` so that I can just maintain the code on the parent repo.

I found this solution

```
git rm --cached submodule-name
git commit -m "Remove submodule entry"
git push
```

But how would I make sure the parent repo tracks files in `syntax-applet` after removing it?

Answer (score 0):

The submodule info is tracked in `.gitmodules` under the project's root.

Edit this `.gitmodules` file. Remove the related submodule definition.